# Recover an interrupted command in zsh

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle

In zsh, if one accidentally interrupted a command (^C), is there a quick way to recover the full interrupted command line?

For example,

```
PROMPT $ this is a long command ^C
PROMPT $ [cursor here]
```

I would like to recover "this is a long command" at the cursor position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to

```
zle-line-init () {
  if [[ -n $ZLE_LINE_ABORTED ]]; then
    local savebuf="$BUFFER" savecur="$CURSOR"
    BUFFER="$ZLE_LINE_ABORTED" 
    CURSOR="$#BUFFER" 
    zle split-undo
    BUFFER="$savebuf" CURSOR="$savecur" 
  fi
}
zle -N zle-line-init
```

Then, in the new input line, undo (`C-/` in emacs mode) would give the aborted line.

reference: http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2015/msg00652.html

I've added a more detailed explanation here: https://www.topbug.net/blog/2016/10/03/restore-the-previously-canceled-command-in-zsh/

Answer (score 0):

It'll be in $ZLE_LINE_ABORTED.

You can bind a widget specifically to restore it. Or create an undo event for it in zle-line-init (using zle split-undo) so that it can be restored by pressing undo.

Comment: Can you elaborate more, please?